# Associative Array PHP manipulation

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to append a key value pair to the "files" key in an associative array as show below but it is taking the key-value pair outside the scope of that key.

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "abc.pdf",
      "size": 17915,
      "type": "application/pdf",
      "action": "NIL"
    }
  ],
  "filesize": 17344
}
```

I want it as specified below

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "abc.pdf",
      "size": 17915,
      "type": "application/pdf",
      "action": "NIL",
      "filesize": 17344
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following but none works.

```
1. $data['filesize'] = $filesize; // appends as shown above
2. $data['files']['filesize'] = $filesize;//
```

Edit as requested, output in console.log():

```
   Object {files: Array[1]}
    files: Array[1]
        0:Object
            name: "abc.pdf"
            size: "1795"
            type:"application/pdf"
            action: "NIL"
        proto: Object
        length:1
__proto__:Array[0]
__proto__:Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$data['files']` is an array, where the first element is another array (and this is the array you want to change).

Try this:

```
$data['files'][0]['filesize'] = $data['filesize'];
```

If you want to completly remove the `filesize` in `$data` you can unset it:

```
unset($data['filesize']);
```

Comment: Correct answer, and I can add that if you want to use a `foreach` you can do `foreach($data['files'] as $key => $array) $array['filesize'] = $filesize;`

Comment: thanks I have tried the above but getting PHP Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array... After searching I realised I was treating an object as an array I changed your line to data->files[0]->filesize = $filesize; but now I am not even seeing filesize when I print the object.

Comment: Use `var_dump` on the object and update the question with the data.

Comment: console.log is javascript and your question is regarding php. Which if them?